# jQuery ajax and javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've used prototype before, and i'm trying to learn jquery now.
The problem: I have an object that makes an ajax call, and i want the success callback to call a function within my object. The problem is that inside the callback function, "this" does not point to my original class.

Example:

```
function C(){
    this.loadData();
}
C.prototype.loadData = function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"URL/",
       dataType:'json',
       success:this.dataRetreived
    });
}
C.prototype.dataRetreived = function(JSON){
    console.info(this);
    console.info(JSON);
}
```

Using Prototype i'd could simply use `.bind(this)`, but jquery has a different way of doing things..

Comment: Incidentally `function.bind` as in Prototype is a standard part of ECMAScript Fifth Edition so you'll be able to use it anyway in the future without having to hack the function prototype.

Comment: @bobince: this will be a nice addition, especially because i tend to use .bind alot...

Comment: Yeah, me too (though through patching `Function.prototype` myself, as I don't use Prototype). Between this, the Strict Mode fixes, and the addition of long-standard Mozilla features to the language, JavaScript is finally getting a bit less horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "proxy" method in jQuery 1.4 that's kind-of like "bind" in Prototype or Functional:

```
  success: $.proxy(instanceOfC, C.prototype.dataRetrieved)
```

Comment: i'm now testing this variant, seems that the .proxy does the trick... but it seems that my json string returned from the server is invalid....
`window.JSON.parse('{ret:"d"}')` seems to be considered invalid in firefox (tried thia in the firebug console and it raises `SyntaxError: JSON.parse { message="JSON.parse",  more...}`. Any ideeas why is says that?

Comment: i've figured it out... seems like the valid syntax for json is `'{"ret":"d"}'`...

Comment: also, there seems to ba an `context` attribtue to the AJAX request, that does the same trick:)